# How to disable SSL for Marklogic Server when the admin page is blocked by SSL

Tags: ssl, marklogic, ca

Our Marklogic 8 Dev Server seems to have its SSL CA expired, which blocked us from accessing the qConsole, Admin page etc. We looked up the document to find a way to disable the SSL, but seems the guide is based on changing configurations in Admin page, which we cannot access at the moment. So is there any way to disable SSL in ways other than admin page, or is there a way to access admin page without SSL event if it is enabled?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it'd be easiest to tell your client to accept the expired cert, thus gaining admin access to make the further changes.

Most clients have a way to force this. If for some reason yours doesn't, try `wget --no-check-certificate` or `curl --insecure` and hit the REST API to make changes.